# How to return a collection of files from a given directory in Elixir?

Tags: file, collections, directory, elixir

In Ruby, I can use

```
target_files = Dir["/some/dir/path/*.rb"]
#=> ["/some/dir/path/foo.rb", "/some/dir/path/bar.rb", "/some/dir/path/baz.rb"]
```

which will return an array of all of the matching files in a directory. How can I do something similar in Elixir?

Comment: There's also this: http://www.ryandaigle.com/a/recursively-list-files-in-elixir.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You're looking for [`Path.wildcard/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Path.html#wildcard/2):

```
iex(1)> Path.wildcard("/tmp/some/dir/path/*.rb")
["/tmp/some/dir/path/bar.rb", "/tmp/some/dir/path/baz.rb",
 "/tmp/some/dir/path/foo.rb"]
iex(2)> Path.wildcard("/tmp/**/*b*.rb")
["/tmp/some/dir/path/bar.rb", "/tmp/some/dir/path/baz.rb"]
```

Comment: `Path.wildcard("/tmp/some/dir/path/*.rb") |> Enum.map(&Path.basename/1)` will output `["bar.rb", "baz.rb",
 "foo.rb"]` in case you only need file name.

Comment: @Dogbert - the link above is broken. It's here now - https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Path.html#wildcard/2

Answer (score 6):

And if you want to recursively gather files with a regex, there's [`:filelib.fold_files/5`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/filelib.html).

Answer (score 1):

`Path.wildcard/1` can handle recursive folders with two stars '**' (it works similar to `Dir.glob` in Ruby). E.g.

`Path.wildcard("../data/??/**/*.yml")`